# PHP string to image

Tags: php, cloudflare

I have big string. Like this

```
ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿáXExifII*1&i2PhotoScape ô ;ÿÛC   !"$"$ÿÛCÿþ<CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 99
ÿÀ;ô"ÿÄ 
ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br    
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ 
ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B¡±Á    #3RðbrÑ
$4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ?û.( ( ( ô¤^¦ô¤^ôZ(¢Q@Q@Q@Q@6O¸iÔÙ>á¦ÊwÿêMcKþ­¿Ý5±¨ª¬>ãºkXÎÄ+þ¥ÿ
ÎJÔ×FëHÛÐÌNË]{ÆôöGÆ©1Å4Ö°¦{SicSÔÆÍ!0¨¦j¨3M
Y¨É=§Þð¦¾Cw"çoÜô¬´m"mJåwNåNàë\¾¤%Þ .nÕ%{£yÏòéøVïÄ·SO·Hªì=zÇX^.·³µ{±«îÌzW=IsKt;0ôívn$Jª¤cÊ/µ8/Ò½6/!ËÅ&ì
ëH¿»÷xÍ7w(]Ä®¸¢¼×Å=Q'·|¹(ë]U÷?âföUÍÌjpdLZmåÌ:»mI!s²TÚÃßÞ³ÐÑyÿíaY­&f[cÆOÝ#¨­{JØyè0ËÍbèwM¦ê$LR=>µè1¢\Ù¸*èAü)aí{XÞçÌ¸rqp~´Õ£¯[{·QÑ"³ÅnÕÎ<SQÕ5M?K¶kû¨ å¤Ðµ{-fÀ^ØHd Ç"N×ÍN)êh@H×ü$_ø¬"öÿr+Ò»/K¡ôÍkKâDKcÒ­×:À?íÜecYêªÚ5· äW Ìµ?»Ç¡©jlîj»§¢)*<
ëô©Ôc_¥(ÝÿÇÃúñOÔ#f~bmØ&w<qRHLÖùGZo¡%GL³ó1P\Þ§ùíVH;éP\ß-h¡L¡ã½,äüh 
j(¢²,(¢(¢JAJzR
ÔZ(¢Q@Q@Q@Q@6O¸iÔÙ>á¡   uõ_e?Lz©­mGýXúÖSõ_¡­¢C1uTÎÇÐÿZÇ¥nêCþ%S{V_tW5}Ñµ=1Å4ÓûSM`ÍS
=©ÒÈ]«÷Å¾³Õ[K»Ö,íïb@§kRäJÍ²YÉÀ½x¯á/~Ð:®Äìk¸ª¶Ò>´áf);óõ¥ÊîæAèQÁ¥fâò|²Z¹Fñ«§âG]çþ^ÏÂÿlVé´¯¶%ÈÎà¾jÝÐ3Ý-£i¦HÐeà
î­;
9x¯#ø/ïbóÅ+hF[´KAäôÆ?ôj#ÁL©ü¹¬çû¸»Ï+#¸s}iÏ;§»wú|ÀÈ
â|cñ@Ð¯½åó$Q¶Ñ*ZIrq^§Ú¨·³· a"Î?þ½SÔ|5£Ï7ö0ÊkµäÑêA6Ló/
ø÷Lñ.¬é:n¢[o$_/N§Ò½GPi#ð÷[­i£è:dºÒÇoo
g# ©øóÃøjÒÿÍ1[_H#¦FLHÝkIYêô4e¶ç+©xßÃÁT½Ý·2X¦áÔnêÖâ«
mÚÖÒî+ÈØnhÛ¿¡­ísÁz'4´këXä¼69sÚÂ}Ãú¿Óx$SBW?JR\ma%+Ýìs·î4}íä¡2¸ã¡þµë~¾kËtßÆåé^AñfÎ(¼D#Ý±î-üØÉé½èGå^·¡Ú>ak4|ÍõÇ5Åw Ü±RÃüLÖ´Í
XßQº
±çi?1ç°¯*Ç:ï¯Mðù·8êGa^ñÁZ~·ãcRÕwÎjÂó7ó?¥[Ò¬m­fðÚ[ÁJ!nqÿ,Å{éFKò%&´<¦·×>×u¯j\^Ø«[äþµÑ|;<ÿmë]_FßøÍ¿Úÿ@Zâ¾»/-×'4ñ
ÐÐ)êÎô8§$ÕDo¥ò+æÖ4²+µø@3âÑÿ\úWJíþäx¹yÿý+z_3Ç¦éÃ:öÍm¸äV>?âcøÙ=«½ÀFXwÍ8¶%ÇµGúç©
æ\ûRâ($
CþéúSß_¥9ÎPÓXáÅ4"×úÙ9ïIot(Iîi×÷¯õ©¼¨²áWpES¶"«N?~µhÕyÇïÅP@?wøÑN·»üh¤QYQEQE¥ ¥=)( aEPEPEPEPMîÓ©²}ÚKQÿV>µ'TúÕÔ~à¬x1þ5´HfuèÎp=sÐWGv3ar?Ù5ÍB~Q\õ÷F´ºEs'T}ìzTÒÆ0y¹ÍH9RK¡ÜÜ[mkr@'ÕWìz&;hãC»sô±/u(¼?Í²Êï-Ú·ÌíÆìàþY©nÂw{øUºþÙ4G|¡¯-ðäæÚ7S¸A½íNXdákÖ´´¼ó`
äÚ|xÔ~×n% o-r­½µ^Hª´Üo©êØoÞ¼_Íª
$+Tÿ?ªÐhv#Äw¾HAú©Y{·½WÒô»¤MOÈÕnÓ/ÃáÇAê+¨ç;ñü/
É* 
=N+ÅWÏ7"!%Høþó@k¨ð3i´è§o2aoæ¹ÛÓ¦+ðÍ£\øµÒE­¦û©º3µôc\^V;0ñÑÈìçC¨"/>L`7ãÿê©ä$ÅRØÃT»WäÉ> TêM1XÆé3ÒQWPØ³}ýäl#Ó°õ]@ÔÅpÉ
#vôâ¹_ÿ´
êÑZë7wPÛmP4­Óß¯jÇoïáJ×õ»Òøom²ÇBF@÷ÍZ¥us^xÂÊMÝö[µ¢í±Óü8Ë3óv5Nîû÷¬_k  c½H9§º`¬[¸®w+hj£«¾çüa·PÖ4?$ª¸v8KWñí!°bÈüyO,þÛsery·¾3þ×ÿª½í &
¬0¥c'½Ì+Ó´b×ãQEÝÔÍ`DË½8ÚOZáàÕ&º½ðòiV)¾%O¸:w5è1¶ó|%r·Àlnè5ËY/¼:Çîÿ@ë`oìµ<lOÆr~,ÓîÁ>/¸¿½ÏÙv¯n§ñ®áÏËáëqõ®ËÇÀ^4$ã÷?ñÕ®7áÿÚ¯ðKâ;ÏÊ*Ì]EUî³Q\ÙôÜ|#R|X÷`s\D=wß7&oîÚ·óÓI{ÈÎ[¥ÿÇÿüÖÍdi#ý5û5¯]¬ÁÃþµ©ìÄ>=©ÿ¬n)ì?x>ñMzp¤noðÓeûëN#õ¤ï¥0(Ï÷ßëQÛÊmíRO÷äúÔIþ´®¬\1«8ÿHZ¶¤öªÓô@À?wøÑN|\¢*

(¢
(¢ÒPÝ(Z-Q@Â( ( ( ( þí-#ô GQû¢²§ÿU«¨ôqÒ:Ú;²ÐÿA¹ÿtÿ*æ åu#6·Cýü«Â ¬1
iu%,TS­¢{|¼·#½i
ÒÌÈ2¬Aö5ÌllZËJÖ¯:Ç4JVêÞõâm/ÃóZKu¬"£|11è:â©Ém§}WRÊ³³mÐó¸«WdpÄu§ê(\* úkWiGcy{.DÓ×·ü;áÛiwÚmÕC4l%-ûÃç¯5ÐjÒVK}BÚÐ½ÔX¾½r«?uE{ý9g?*²üØÁ©´¿6£._aGq2{QI´¬÷9'ÌõèSVÖÞ(¾KÒ"ÑFÌ;sÙÆzÔzÐÊ5FÀÝ>0Àö´nñ
÷ÛM£
gj
#HÓêöHæB#é[vû<B£
¨ÀWã+¨ô{=?JcûLîgñ"º Íöí+ÉCã?Zá¾"Ôuë4^AºXÐ^n#K¿Ý{.ÚtÒ¯öõì@ÂSÿAú¿pÅ¸u=+-ÍÕuMB.b[£b:gc? *üN² äJÖ: ïxÅßÖþ*ñ¼÷÷Z¤öãÊT0¹9ÉúâOÀnu¦ÞÈ5ôWâ¹¬ÖÐen+C©^H"kU·ðØå7Z+©éÂ)ÁJ[|:Ò"Ð|/g§ù4BI«7­\Õîc·¶y¤`ª³zTÑi8Íq¥_jÑC»?d»\|Ò3V»6®ã=2Ké\?4Ä@üñ[^
fºþÂã>kÇ÷s^SðÛ_Ôü/Þ±t'·í?
!A´ õfoý½CF£ñÕ¾SËØ´H¿3YU´d½lgR¢¨­ßø³sm¥xNF9iQV4,IÚOjóYõ»ÏmÒÅ|ÃÊw±ùðç^¡ñQú;°Uñÿ|×
h?Ó¼;ÿ^ïÿ 
÷0é(hxoÍ©ÇøÛIAà\ÝÜOs:LHgl(;S£Æð(Æ®«â"øÆJÎ °=~T®[ÀüiX¯)|G[Ýj½U¢è*Ì?xW7f=zÁÄME©ÿÐyì=z?ÁQÿ{óÿNãÿB®[£)lzÿ»Zµ¥ÇäîÖ­v3C   ýë
øÿ
/õÇéScÐÀ(=( ô¤1;
l}iÞZkÿ¬ZhE)HYpiçÍ;T%ßÞ«Z}ãô«±,¿ÍW¥~5jÍWþ>OÖ¡Ð±l?wøÑN¶ºüh©c,QE%Q@Q@Ý(Z¥@¢(QEQEQEQER7JZFé@µ²n~ìu­¨ö¬¹mÙNp>ÍsþéþUÅÆß/»YGú=ÇûùW`/#¡­¤Ñ·µCtí´*T8ª×ÓE
nxãí0Ên.qnº0Ý("IG-A»â Hñ>¯§4÷\¦A÷¯:Ô|;âS±°µlì?xÞá{~5Î/Á/#´\ßM!ä±oò­T¹#¨þ®ê=DñîªÌ¶÷

Ôâ&òd7×õÈü1ð.£êz©y}r÷wùýÐ;#1ñÛ¹÷®jûàôIöÄ:r£ä0ßÍoøq¼kiñk7Öw7ÖÈµÚ®dôeãk{´£V2Ñ¤Kf³ÇâÝR´Û÷ET     í`3Ð÷ëUtbÉ#ÔVV"ndÿYßJï4ÍPé±<ñ£Ýn9nT`ÒêÑÜ[ÐöìD9ëëZº°Z6r<<ítIà2áý¬ÿ¬:ý;W<Ð¬ôO*iXíü?ãøWD÷ñÁ¦$l`(º;
ó:åÜ¨>¤^Ý0 9ÀîÇðÍqbeIáá$Óx[Q4ù$Ô59¦\ÿ Ú?¯éWmïÖfC÷NTúæõin.¼Kd-I{]21½¿¾§­njÆâÄáOGOôút®IÕ»Ó¡êP£hûÝMÈõWÆdÚC×ÃçÍ$OOLómvMGNÈHt:~#µs¯ªßÝ8EâaØ`â¡âm£G\p«¦v:¤Ý3+2k_[vðÍü×O²oEïMÒô{Ë§FÈÉûÒ¨ür¹Cø~ñ¡¥8Ôÿ0$~@ÔGNäI("uí«m6Ò1o¥XÏä¬+Üqó7ë^«¼W.Ô/¬Õ+?îötÀã5ã?u;Á)ÄJÒ»êGó5êú,e¥åÀgÉÐäÔVµ¹|ÿC+[ù~¦ïg7ºòãófHªç©§â+Ï>Ë«\jÚÍv±¤
°/ÌÑÔít¹·JÉ
WæSßüóXN½¢û%#é´W©TrLòñåw8èÖpø3Æº¼Ó¤ÃJÅ|©Xþ
ãKêk¨ø=ºx'ÆQ¼ñ«´À*µ+ðaÎ÷5Õøz_ÖÃÐUzÕh~è«0W64`è+Ñ¾ýµz;oýW@8èÝàõ¶ÿÙtÒÝËcÑ´±Çÿrµ+3Lÿ¶ÿr´ë±¢ÿ×§õ©»ÓbLûSQCh=( ÒÑÚ¿Ö
QÔ
ßJb3ïµ^ÌrÆ§¼ë/Ö¢²­h¶%î_­Võ«0u5YÿãàýM.£è[·ñ¢Üþî(¢¤ ¢(¢(¥Ct¡zP!h¢QEQEQEQER7J£¨ö¬¯õiZÚQY_êÒ¶Æl«pqkré®5Xì®Ô(tB¸5ÆÂçMcèkHÆñ6»¦Ky0.TePM'Âß³/u¦3ÏpwÚDü®?*äõ§TÕå.Ááb+vÚÃÇôÍaHP0)8{8ë¹¥7Ï#Zff|ç4nqQ  qÔt¬gÅ¶Ör¡·ä¯¯ó®&îzMlkËòç+O¶Ó£.'rÝUHéïU<'w¬Û5ýÖl­óÎ]ý[é]IÍ&Bu:!±@88©$·t©Ó
RàVFLç5kp~\×-k¡[ÙßKp^Yþê±G wýk¾»YÁé\óD%u©omB=©D)Î=ñÁúÕ·Çï+hÀã7ö/4ûk¨
Èû½¿Jäï¼;µâOlæ&=ÔpßQ]øïSZ¡soæ÷Ù¢Tîk
¬¯¡BQ÷8ÔWþÓºî·e¡Ü´(ÐÌÍ%Xð¼wà÷Ëràte?|³ñ
èë?5;[;ì[ÆßÝÚ6ÿ<þuQ÷Q5u7<¨[ÙhÑÙÚÛrãtÒ4¥$û(ÇæM{æÀ²Üdýæ¼?O¹·XÆÉ2±ìÇõ$ýk×~]%ÿ$Üð¯+ùñ\ÕUõ'dvQC+¼_.øÔ¨÷ÿ~µÄÝi2¶·£C>£q$AdÚ¨|±£kkK¾Ûs¡¹B   ÷OþµM¯D±øL;i@ú®ü®iÜóqñi£ñ®aoàOI²oY¸vùî§sÍ`x#þAQ~5ÐüBÔ¬WÁ>1·7pù¯1
ÆOÊ«ðIÆzâ¥ñ|=[ï
§   àU¨OÍ\ÙpôèÿSP~2 ó?ýjóXOJôÏjMæ¥&8(ýMtÒÝËcÐtÏøûo÷iÖfÿMþåi×c1CAùñíJzdg2¥IÞÂÒJoqAæA@ûÃéAûôÄgÜã|úÓ-Ð/ær~y3Ó4èJç*0*É,[Õvÿ^~¦¬ÃñUÛÏÔÑÔe?Õþ4RC÷(¤À³ETQEQE#t¡zPÝ)GJQE
(¢
(¢
(¢
(¢
J(=(¡ÔVEßúµ­}C¨¬{¿õb¶ÆlßaþÍqì;Ç °®ÖÔæCô®PW]Jåqæ5g[dÙtú¼5Y×??Ê1Ô1^áæ[">^IÇZãu'Tde8V^@çWYá·ªªË°.0)W÷¥c|?º®ÍmKbýC9ÛøVFmï5oìôPWÌ;Pmjé¹ötQVô+H­4Ù.%G±»¹ÿ¯ãq÷­Ñ§:&ú²ÊÕP¨£Õ2
æÅU¸¿ò5HíKe¡ÆsY;»ÈÆ0oDhi#cÊä©5ÐSÖ¡É Plàñ¨Ê3Ïzx¸F`iÇ±®låFzQ°Õ` '¥G!Ò ¢Xâ³®ìÑ}=kOc¿Bh6r7sV®ÅÍn§=ÔbOwrOjùßPÓ­æø«ý©8Ô%xä?ÀÁÉöéøWÔòiK2*æ¸_ü2R½:r-nÈÃL¬ér=3Í)Ó´5x½â:·ßMÕ<ÈGî\f#ýÞÊ~+Ñ~2éZ»2ìöSÿdÏÓ5[Pðæµ§´¿²)ÂÌ#^¿A-ÐöÑ È"ÉÝ^9úó\RrÙ4²7ôøeöÝrÑüJÜí­½_ETuíÀ/%)'
ò~4Ë;#¨ØÁ{nØIGöîó­+Î;ÝæÙ&[c?^k£xUMu81v5èy_ì¬áð'hT|©Xaý3é×ñÆ¯¦¿üaw<JÁBçå_Jæ|"ò&ou&fØ
ì}«Û¬§jUQ²;øQ1Vb?5rQë;¯"8;ÑÉÀb:~­ý÷íÍ´)Sktyu[Î7&©¤«EÞ=|ØO½Sàzº«öÂý
¼é^»ð9öf§!ôüjèüG=×J?émþåjÖNstßîV±é]ÅE÷ÍKQÄ>cRPÆQE øÿ
ù¨þ?Â3¤ò3É¦Z¹õ©&aÛ&8ÂHTt­.A,K¯ÿ-Ö­¨ÀSþ[HeGÉE,_rL    è¢( ( n¢ºRÐ ¢E
(¢
(¢
(¢
(¢

¨õuÊ~¯¨EcÜýÏÂ·ÆlÌþðý+Õ#'Yºûù®®Ìþðý+Õ5»÷¿¥e_á.æcé¨u';a,X23ÈT{*ÔÿXmìÙoìÀ$ÊÊs§¡«¸xÛÚ=cHÖ$é/§['ÆAM½¹®)óÚ'A8¯ë©vþU%u9g"¶¦ÇiøPgëkOÓ$Ö¹4SÇõ¦×Rw§Ç°j¹M++ÍE.fºÕÊ×Ú¸Éµs{â1I>­oYßêV¯¤©nHÇÌ3ÇÖ¹íB½±b³Ç9Ý»w¾ksv²;iÆú³®K²aç­bkwÓÛÛ<¨Èá@êXð]*óX^"ÕíìZÝd*](§»vþuÉ'rá
t/èf}È·ò¡»+¼Ä§³]$rÆ«eüë´¹¾ej#ód¸ç×<V:_3}{q9=U[Ë_ÓÖ¥I-§M½[7d¾#`Äzvªk9wËSVkxvAAìsU·~´^ìÐÛ´mØâµ`@Â°lgVÝó]´¬rUMÄCÂ§µXVS_WMk³XÓ#¸°£cósDÛq²(L¬J°?/^­^±pÃçõ«UQ\Õ)§©ÛB³ç~[Í
¬°Ü
¤Hä2E'¬RÛy+,¤dõÅn\ÄaÊçGfR;¶äåX:µlîdf_!ÙIäF3ùVT)¨TIø9&ÑäÞ2$ðÂÆ£>0?ÙZç~.ýÈÄF¹½+wÅºè~ ÓIu£HòHPGá\ÞD0}  ÃÛ`:ãñ®¼\J(ó±¯¨[C#î·g?6J7{ýk_GuAü|ÿ{Vlq2+ñ'5M7][K[fXÑr7ù§Ú¢3\ög[êÎµG±Ààµí?F<)xàýëÿÐE|·¡xÄFí¡*Ý¦Ûúb¾øq<þ[qµÌÏaZÑR<É½ËE?é/þíl£ÇÛjÙnÖ÷1Cbê~´údmÉZ}aE­ â&¿}©IçZÔ~ùÇ×ùÓ;{Ux¦31ÎiÑ>â[Ö®ÎäIÉªkþ´Õ?Ê«Fs%4¸¾ïãE,L6ÑRÆMET(¢(¢Gáh)$#POÉLB¯JZjV#ÔRh¤Ü=E.E
)2=hÈõ ¢2(¢Z2( ô£#Öî¸ê(©Y+øV¦¤ß:Ö<ÍÅn´F{½ìÏïé\ö¡o4úýÂC9$tíÅl¬XíÉ'½?{ÅHÉêkµh5dtÓ¡$îÌè´ÔFi0ì~5j0N(q¸P¾â¸ÜßC²1IP«Ó&¢O3ô«.1¨8G!Ç#7-]¤d2/PTr?
¤ÚÍ?íµÔýÆùIüê×ö¶Ëk¸
³Aô"#ÙÏD¸>¸"£+gï!;¨òrý +Õ<+m.°JZTM¨­Ê®zèOô­«"Úâc>[öh~Uys­hSºÞYÄ±YÞ_ê+:ÿ7¥«÷%¯aÏäRb:&Î   4è5X52a¬LÇUxüOlRCa6ßÞ¾ßaXJ¾g+i-8Á{4Ã¤S³¯/àäRHÇ3}\ÒädsG¡bÑB¯i í\ò[EnO1Õd?×4ÍFûS±´itûVÔ$!gXÉÿ?Jè§+heR*[´394N¾µÁGãÝ:Ø"k]é.ÃµÀÉ>n6ûê¶×VxÖHeIÆUäõ®®sÙjkO*óVUä7^*´úúÖ}ÕúÕ¦PhÓñ    oøE.<yu>áôÍs·q\näýär.É1ØÖåÈ»Ñ¥¶Îw8úæ¹MÍÛui"bä«Ú¹qwMN;ç<"eÿSµ¸þVtUp°
X~¸vDÑ¤_"=+Úü_¨C¡xbæþèH!NX¢ÀÇ<Wé2Ç©$VóJ"Þqx5×ÞRçêoWB®XZN6ºòÚçGï@«Å0èvÓJ³LÌ¼â¥°UFK©­QT3Ï©¬õ<±°YÄ
¹Å}
ðváý¸A·Ìyýwý+ÁTq^ûð­?Y9æFÃq®¬2÷¨ô74l}© ´ý+D?é}qüëmúWcÜÅl2#OÒ¤=ª(>ù5)íIîÓXóN¦1æH¾óR±äÒCÔÒ9ûÆ eÈ~Z±ÜRC*Ô_tV§¥Aß©Wî9ö¨`ûôµàýh¤NëE!©j é|ç¨ËtUO9¨ó¹nç=*¯ôyÏ@\På²VÝ·=*/5/j®!É¿tFY3ÂH$4yOV¬¹û<Þèi7·­(½hæ$þãR3êÚ½½hó`°ÐòÌoùPdùæÿ8;zÑæ5Èvæ7÷þù4y¤uVü©þkR^d!äÇò¨>Ô¼Æ)¶·g¥ý^Üæ_*lÇä
aêzû#íÖ¦u£Mj\(ÊoBÆ­©!dg'×µg ðÄÕsõ=é7Ìÿ{çÔ¯)½OBÁh]wÈÂM4Î>Ü[[òÊ z­sªEçGaûÎG=yãY9$h Í
Û~VrßZòOJdÎj+[wîcº:Ó¸F:_ËÛÔò1P£R¬üÆ©ù÷'"KwP:0=jí'LÕ¥Ìs+7ãþ`Ñ¯CnX¥«-ÜÃ£j»[YÆ:IoçU"ÐtÓýÔ"?¥sð¯ïí'wÑ|Q¨@¬så]2}p@ük¥ÐômJÆÓv¯÷à[«*cþj¹[ÝãEhcñ
©ºÚÁqhüý©\# ÿiO_¨üoÌï$a%!¿µ»`LrÅ³Ñ ÿ#>{ñWE- w»B|¨¸
ìDpçAl
)oJÎE¨Øk Ç"cÏAÅHjAY´=ÆöÍFÐÂ®ãÔw-3,¡V]Ã¡½s¾ÓK<ÚTè·,s¾ÄB}Z3o©÷®½Ðg5ÆÙÈ¡6¶³<ÇWÅÚgÔ¬F«f¿òù§!Ü£ÕáÉ#ê¥Ò³ôï®¬¬&«<ú{õ½¤kñ¬oïÎ³£Mý®¸]Â¤§ÒXú8÷ëïNQU4½<Ò¶>l
"ï¼*qiÕºA|¬=ë¹ñ]î®E¥xÏOI¿n¢blîýÑÝ?ì·"»@·`pr2>½ªeNÏJ7D^$¶çK{xí^â9B=Àøþåà­rÆo*ÏI»6ÒáDdíõSCÃí¾×ì¦l_)eozí ¶]t!&yÕg8I9Ûø[Ä!F4{¿ûâ®Gáù]ß5ôJÚ§÷iâÙ?º+_`»{F|ú×Òn¿ïößZÍeà«+iÁI"YÁ$àÖÀðYEÎ1ZÓ¹2BÂt´´ácµ«ý©e ÀèF+¿§¯Ê8«Gbyu³IF«QJÈÚ4.§chèìJ°o¡«µpé3ÆrÊ}Z·Ôõ8_ö¹«mNNÒüÄè4¹ºSûVzÕÂÞÏáCkÇú¥#Ó8®¥¡»f~ÎLß¡úÔr#ý
f[ëùÓn}4ëZÏÊm®K0è+Xâ¨½y%ØÛG­[N/ fSæÇ­Oý©dfú
ÓëTm~tO$»k÷éP[ª
nÈº8ÊÔqjÖjÙ2}*V.ûkï§>ÆÂt?Z*zµ\ý¡G=Á¢«ÛÒþe÷ åbØSíNØ}©§@  °úÎiô.}éA m>»Ù4üÒæ·ØÑ´zÊPh<Ê
4q@a}E.ûÃó©8¥À _ï
\QR`Qí@àzLQRa}T¾¿´³Rfp÷GZ+àUOP¶²Bd`[²µ¯ÏpJÚ :gÈ4w,\õ'ÂuÔvÔé§oYhx¿Äßø_l|¦·Ò\]^9?"½oJº÷Nú9DÊÓÁÃ|]Ð${xµûtyË¾   |Î®8ôÍfü6×¢ÓgÃ×î¶oÓæfàÉOoP=ëõ]fíù_qT?sQÓ{=Qê/8Ùæ;í±ª\ßÜ*Ï0ÄzÈÃùUíæI)¡è*KS·µ¶àW;ó=(Ù=Ìû¸ììPÏw!LrîÝ>¹§UÕ/UìFÈæ9\q@;Ô¤I­Þ²E¢?ç¡ÿ
ê­v¶ñ2&í¸½7J)ÓçwÙR§³Óv?Ã^«,ÑÅupZ¯ïJ{}k°û4PE¶%:§¤¼pÄ¯
5¡qBªHÈ¯J8E{¨ó*T¥©äÂæ¤P¾IcÉ)ðFWváÐg5NåÏÌÀü½©YÅ]ñ;!I$8"²ïµÏ+È2qòÙèpHÏæ*Ù¸6{u¯,ñ^§uwu>lLßºÙbÌ}±ýkuÔõpxuRV{#Õæa,L
°­fÞ,$slÇðã­púTÞ&ÒV'Eqýèã$`zõÇ¯é[Å6Ò©.ÖèÊÝE7R2]iûº¢h<káÖÛI¬ZG08!óé]
¼©*,H®eYNAâÞ,±ðö«|­¤éÊu0°®ìÛÈëÅzÃÍ*÷G°I
"¹ÜÈ¬vß ü+7(ÞÈªøXÓw×±Ù'Ö¤ÔTrÅ3ÏbGNh`OJ\`ñJGlÐI¯Ö£aj°ãM+"    Ç$:ÔmÁÀTÝð5$)XeoIÒüA¥M¥kqÝÚJ0QÇ úÔØEy«þjQ[æç^ð´ò·©i­èÐô>×´G ô¥¸Û9-.¢Á*g"µô³ÕT§­ÑÀè^éðÏ¦Éö²NAhÈÀn¢½ÇN|[FI;FOá_;øÊÒëáÈº×laöÉ£ÁÜ7 ÁÞ£68Þ   Ï99é_´¢ÛB.</4 ¯2[Ý§è
þ­ðøw7QÇ©t>FÜoÒ¤ý^Qð÷ã¼_®Á¡ÛÃ¨XêçËKÔ#   ÀecÎêzµÒî´g*Ôwû&³u«¿*ÜR|£k óõ5Îjfâã9Ê)ÂâÆb*mõ5§f+H©æÌ%sP;*µI¿Å|Ã;l['d;NÕëP ri«´:º!¨_r_1Þ$Ò1Á÷¦nïI¸Î¬¥S¹j#È&¦J1ÞàúÔs¡ò±wqÐÞ¢«âå½4yRc4µ<ÍÈL¿÷Aüh£ôSöTw©Ù¨ýáùÓ¼ÅþðüëînyÛ©A¨C¯¨üéÁÅ\Òî¨ÃQ»ëL    3Fj0Ô»¨¸fÕáëFáëEÇb@ÔíÕaëKz.%ÝLUK;Cq:Cv=;z×1ªßËs!U%TPåevT äìú¶¿ÑÚÿßUÏ»ÍrÛÜ'Öy÷©Q6®   ¸êTsÓ¡ßN`´Üi(`¯'µ#æD
F:EUzÖf#ºHeÄëÀÈ5óßÅ}_Þ£Lf]
â@mn£<ØË=9ÁíëÏÐLñ¤^lÍ<×âËÛMWNNº)¬æR#
&ÒZR¶V8üP{¸cÐüC*[j§îæ<»ÄìÊG½Gå["ÿûZïÊGÌ
~b_jðßø~
:é­ÖûíZLt~ò.¼G=zðA^©ðª{_Ú<jTHC$ÜäY?}£z>Ö¨µ;øUb@08è(ºÔÔåQì*·9àÏaöò
kQòÆÈ(®i]§Ýäñ]L)ãîñ^q§ê
"E-WnØ³øÖ»0ÓæG.&+.M",¸¬}VxÞ)Æ;w4W^eÁµJö\J898¢µKû¨ÓG§!d·ÂÀz×£i&ËÄÜóM/¸G~UèPÈ² tÅdêvÑÏ0¸~þ>ÔzWâz8z­®(³ÇËMºq%Å¤ñ©ìdYâ%3×wUÔíÎ*¹¬¤âÊ6e¥°ÿE¶%ôEùV\
l`û¹íVãN)¨T{µ"dP8¥UãWc°ã¦äÓ®)­1ýiÒØÇJb¡¬¼ôâËJò9¦¦¹ÕJ·Z²^=jìÝS°ír¦´ÝÚµ¬¨²DÀVb+äïxe<ãyôé­ìfk&Üpì;Oè­}fPÈàgó_ÚÃ««|>­´y¹ÒÜH
õØxaôÇ?oR¹Í¦l|+ö/Z]¼×1Ko8tÕAt`rÁè23ë_nø;ÇÞñM-¥êöóÝÁû¹AÇ?»' ~cÜ×Áº-ÐUYºm'rýáG¾JÛÙ{ms$¶óË
õ   @åX¢D#· ûgê+Ð¨¹´¹æÇMO¸õ@[xÛ<ÕåëùÿÀ_nÈ|M\§Ü7q®$\yz¨Áú×µi§eíÌwò«£dþ¿µ|ÎjªÂkhwáÔd´5äÒÄã­»p~+Ã]t:Õ=&LýiCüUul­?95Ñ±ò'Ðp(ÞqÅKÒ4¤óa<Òæ¥Èv$ÖO}E*¿jqd´.MæÙ¤É=ª¯`µÅ,3Ò0h«æØ,2|ß?ýzDýØß?ýzE8
ûÞDx+ù-ýáùRù/ýñÿ|ÕRãr ¹[È}ïþ½4ÛÊzKøÿ^®K9îRû4ÿóÜÿß4e¸ÿ¦ðWñK=²µ¸ÿ¶ÿ¾E(¶¹ÿ¶ÿ¾jî(£ÙOì÷]®¿ñÏþ½1áºD,×jÿ¦ýz¿YÍÀ\Ee¨äCM¶g\ÈÒäÈÙ¿LÖ4òÄÞ¤½¼2¶Å8AÓÞ©³äã5ÏV¢z#¾&µeyÁ§»FOãUcô×
W9Åcs£±q0Qòò@ªeHÌ²°UóQÉ Ù¸ôÅr~#Õîf¶öÀxõ.ì'µç»fHl    Á>µç¾*ÖÞ8Hýzàþ¡®jQÆ¬ zZóÍZåî&ivÍ)]Ô©¤®rß5M*c¸ï~ã^ÉáßJ³O¨¯ñJ>§¨ÅfØ¬ô¯vðlO-½¾{"ÿ*Õ{±G=_zLì!Fw¨õVXr9âµVÚÉ¥+«ä5
júk&2@9è:UNIîhÊ_    1Ô'Èsî
zôWm:ÙÑÉ`¸¯!AQ³ûV^«!Æ~µèÞveµ«É¹âÔ Ö¯ÜS±8ÅµäZ²2©NH9JÒ@±1# ¨=Í×øOãRÌ¢BÈxVÍ>[^îÆ&«Û©mlåAî=¨PÓCsRhÑÂU ºva°ý-ËcÜñùVùúuâ­Ó9¿ÃJÉNêÌítâãÔÒÆS9Så?úÁéï[QdpTúU1<3Àbr¡À$ðj-.gµco7ú¬áÓÚXyÆýQ¨¨ã"O
sKØÇÒÎåq23òçÕ"óÉâ¢ÇÍô¥ÜsöëAqÆI÷¨ØHpTãI=É2´Õb½jn]³Þ¢,sÒði    ã¯Z.-~ø.E<:Õyß'¤Æ¤R PkC¨hWv3ÑÍF ðjÄ£+ï©3b&¿)X$®|KäÄÚ|ÞRInòÀPp%K`{g¯o«[ÙIk#Mµ iÛæC½;uôoãE¤Võ5u+
ÎÉ8ÞA?ÖEÕÖ§h^DVOøã'þ&PØtÏl5ë'Íû<£Ë&»èWÚ´nM³B®vÙ®çÂæ± êôÖ·ÞóãÕzW&
Ö­º(ÐÀc'¸ÚO>µ¸XÆLaÎ§,+WF´âÏxðÅ
?P)k® Ón¾ïÂçëÕ=ëÐ£$A$nd2=E|­3Êã]sÅlxcÆz×¥Î:Ó9kiI(~Ý?Jùü^M   ûÔg±×
ò>Î*Epqø¢xl)/Ù/æÚb'ýÑ¿µuáù×ÎU¥Rf¬ÎÈ¸É]8 9'¥EÔäÓÆ3YÜv'V÷ ·Ö¡©(¸¬<=;ù¦`
t¡14*¶x`iåxâ)ÊÄsÛ½mLÞ2(§py¢´±7; )ÂS~xf
ZP(RE´RRÐHMÓIï@¸ ¤á@æ¸½_P{+ÂÒ®xVYd0DrúZÁÞç5ÍZ§Dwa¨ý¦8¿¨Á5>1úÓ¤U+zs×½W2c;«ï,<8M¼Ù'ùGËÜÓÕ·)µÏë~"uÝ

;½&ÒÜ´zø³T0[HïGjáuKèícÙ±3É¥Ö5Kf4´¬zÒ¹lË{.ÔÜû3Ô±®yÎìê¥JËR®£q%ÌçõÑ46çdm¹­z÷|+¤ky© iqòÜû×1âÍ;í/µG&fâ¾³·[¢éÏx$×¼xBÐEmé+ðö#på9úW¡èvmjH§{ÊÆì0¤yl`u¿ì<ÍþH<æ¬YÄF3ZÖê+DÜÉÎQÙF@¨@èEoh-ïRAÀèyí[@1U5Àtëô®$3dz¢³Y¹ËÈ#±ªÚÛ8.9¥¶¼+[Ðzäu+¶°ÖÞc¶)ôü{Q)Yés-z>#n/cMí1ß½mÛ-¾£h²m½¡§èþMå¶r¦B¿*þÕ¦9Ó/ZÖC]¾R½?¬î>nxÙnZÅúS,ºK@Ù=Ì_jK¿XÇft\©ieUcè+±tkv¡äf¸]Ñ¤ÆEdmð181¸ô>ß=S¿B¨U§)(ÕÓÌßðn¿i«[o12v:`à«È ö5ÓÇ(ÃÛÒ¾cðG¼[áÏ0ØøÖY%¹aÎSÇi28nÙn¸ëÒ¾ó[ÔP¤¯ ó'°í%umIç¸y
ªáº6øuªìÇ=GáQÈË@<ÓLò)96q¨¤LÎrN*?0YNAô¨Ì¸¨÷/*£®¤¯'\Ó9¦núRRe-ÁÁéLÞxô¦3ñ9¦îÊóÒ4JÏPIÎI¤i6àQ»ðq@Ð÷s´U'Ãwæ¥wã9ªÒ  éÅKóí7ÇÓcK5çÜ3×öÚ§ZÞjb·¸x"@3ÙA1»#>æ½ö¥·
­iS)ä[¾à=ñ¯>ÄñÉ&ÆXøÜ1ýkÖ¡­(>#J²;]Ly|5©M¨É:ÞEÐ\pzÈíÍ]³Ìú]´¤ä¼@ä{Ö³¼S=ñ²±ñ*:Û=Å°æÎ    <ô9úb¤ÑæF´àùj>TKUsZv½;3MÙòäÛøt¦*YT#×¥T°}ÐÎé Çä*ø9LÖ,Ý%c2hØèJ°ä8 ûWsàú¶ée¯+êVJ@ËtS÷×zäXHàYóÆ aYÖ£N¼yj+¢Uàï}_á­Iñ½Òo¢ºø2F^ ýkXs_iÚ¡¢Þ­þ{5ÊÿmûÐc^¹àÐ1ÏÅÆàËuÊvN£ê3ô¯ÅdÕ)ûÔ}åøÿÁ:!OIè{°èiÁJËÓ5+P¶æÇQµ¸Atjòô µâÊÕ §±g<S¿
GLÔ«ÇZHL^iâµ¼¤1Ê>¡¢¦+Eoì;5£×gx!ú?áâSôjãÖò6zuö§ÕH8¯cûB¬~ÑÉìS;hüAh~òºþµb=jÁáÞW5à$Áô¤eÂÜtÓY½Hïf?ª¦z70Ì3¨ãý"¼®ÚùÑFIÐÖµÞ£t3+.r8aÎ+ªsJO¢·äL°µã©ßfÖ~«Øj1«[N¥gaá¿*Ðë^¼'®h»£¦[SfM:åÐá&#ëV±L¸K¥Oâ*À·<±]Ý·IÔéAØÆ7%OÔqUïfEOS^d¡Q4*sUg¹r+2{À'Ê¼ÕÔOlVnCä5uíD&å[nEpÉÝêkCYºöÌD·|!ðøÜ"j:Ú²¡å î}ÍO,ª; u!F7ÉiÔüK 1)ÕzÈü]Öá½?DA,à¬aÓéé]{C
¼"#XãQª0f]!bq]PÃÆîÏ:¶2utZ#ùÍswvBY#½u×6¬TVY·ýæ¬ë«ve+T-nÙÀÆ¨R$VVJå:ï¡¡h½9­Æ5NßUpEic-IÞªÝÈA=F*Wn*´ÒmÕóör[\GrØãÐÕijzXWÉ rïQÝÝ¬D¤ê_ìj;]`Û±ÛÍþéÔzÒêHì§Ï¤eªO"X~WÇQÝ²d×abp@'ïËÕt¹aêË¾9Î£¡ãYOsef×úhyfc°¨»³:¹Vñþ¼ëN¿)¥Ó~Çø½¾µ§ò¶  bkÇô?
{Ik©¬±ùAÎÆÁïéô«ÆÊ)  ÚYAëÍT½×cEMë¡röÚÊiI­ãgCò±S")À<vVIÁ-øÕwçÉ<rÝ^a*37lJ¢óäòi¦`­+Þg©ÛnñAüj¢N;Òù h%Ç¯4ÕÃUC/$i¹ÍÚÉ·:acmUóíQùÄ·>Åã"ã¢ó<Uq riDÏLT·JîÎx¨&n3Ú'Ï?µáµí&#?õ«ÍbwS%¥ ´wÕ¢òÙpÊæ9=*H>õÜþÓónñeáµófÿ
àü4û¯6Âdyd¤îÜãÎ[Ô??ÃÕ¡¥$yõ¬Ðë/·kMÄÁVÚ0bÕ
ÿj´ôBé0"p½é¾/µWÿhÓð´Ë?qO¦0GãPiÍ³Mè(º¹T×,¬Í½6oÝ\¿ýh¤Ù\:s\ý¬¸·ÔÉþj9ù'=:V- 'Í× íU.eUù²ÁÏ5RkÅEÜì1\Ö¥¨ËuöXª¾GojqÈìkIz·y6ÿ9Ï,:
¹kk3ã5[K("UA{VU´½¶2åæÕm(à×E¡ëúÆêöÄþß)ú¹(ny®jâ\J¦­%t.T¶=¿Âÿ·à× Q>Ñãþ¿Ô~Uéö7P^[Gsm"K*èr¯Vô(Æì}+©ðGÄß
^   ¹°výý¹?øòú7ó¯Bk·GþFô±.:OT}1(5áéýª\éwk*8ÎÃPG¨­Õëçýé¾Y«3®Vz¢O¡¢£ÉúQ[èa©Æ²&¾RGJ³ö§¬+KBÇ?tVD¹UaÏ«RjV:TSÍIf$n^Xr)à¨mØ¨OËÔû
z·p²±j  ÿ{(ÈÈl¡ªùZ³«`¸pÃ¶8æ¨I¨ÁmæK#]²£<86o&³¨¤®»mÓ÷¿úÕt0Ò®ùPå5OVwÿm&ñu)IX?ÅÿJôU5ËèØEb·` s_c£Ô"xÕ¦ç+²å-F­p5×sñyòêd>rIóKûÀ÷#Ö¼ëQ»1£¡¯y-U®ììî­Í¬2×z\µ0êNéØï£#ÊÕÏ¯®YÎ   4Í#FÔ5«±»JÇ«º£Üö¯sÁ^_1´ÔÏ båÕ³±³°·YÛEcøQqXÇïï3icÕ½Õ©ÅøOÀöz$k=Ø[«Þ»ùSéþ5¹r­y"ªIOJëPQVG*¼<$öª×'¥tMmÔÃj=(qÎ}ìÁC\åÜnzï¥·Â+¾ý:_@Æ¹±C«
-Y\ò*ô1Q©°=kÅ-Ú¤\dmÒ§íMÆ398¨n>eïWjy5èY»U    ·0yìÑôw¯.ñ-ýÿõ)¢{ÙÏ òd9?g¦Öô^àûé^·n¾c³þUËxïKfO8 uuÄFA¦ß*º:ðõy'g±7ît+{G»}½Ãym!?"1Ä0N3éÍk¦«n5D_"]Z2s±Ç_¨÷ïÁ®ýàÒ[èDJ0Èô5á;GL¿m×yc³37Î?tóÒ§Ú^g|U9AôüSÇ
ÔáÕ[ðÂ7ui»jJAÎ}#$­z7µ   þÀ](WP+"×PW¶ãñgí1AÁ¬ÜÙJ©    tëÔèïpÚ8ªïuóüÄëXæ÷Ù8ªÍ|sÉã>´ùÎ~S}§È'Ã35öàyÝíV!¸95W¬j,ëÏjGg5¼Aå¨×¥!iÈæ©¼6(2qH,[ó=j)&ÁÚ3UL­3~{Ñp±tINîÔy¿6C~½j?*T|7^A¥q´iK/¡ÅWpS¯$ÅFIâ©ÝOµ2OÌ>uý£nDþ;+õÑ¦¹cýk´vK8­­GÒ[î¸wq®9µ%Ôüq«]oÞ¿hòÔ@ú£{3µ´Ó¤¿¸1ü\c?:õáS<IÎõ$ËÞ$Ôã¹¶mR$dëÓ¸ü©Ð9Ê%ô@åX×0\â(Whecp9ýGó«sÎ §Â.2»lÒlÛ¼ÄÒÉt#¨úViG
.y£qwÁb~<¥sØYÔX
ÙcÀýqî<±äZÀCqxX­Ûy6¨®ÖFJ\ÎçAm/ö¹ÉÆk'ãÔÑÉêjR4¹¯m8ñÁ««8± jÒÉî0j¼óÓç=j ÛïQ±
R!³­ð/¯|-¬Ã{    2Ûît9áÇô>õõwµ?\Ò Ôô¹ÄÖÓ.T÷¸#±ñ©æ»ï>?¸ð~±åÎÏ.rGÚa?ß_qúÃfgúÄ9áñ/ÄÖ~GË-«÷SETµ¼´¼µòÒå%·ºSÐÑ_3v´hì<úGÛÀ-¼¸wqXzÆ­geupEÇïW­øãT¸FÃÚvâåâç*¿õ?)S¡:²ÑÞÈô[ýZÒÆ#syq/BíÿõëÔ|p.ÉKBðfq×è?Æ¼íôëBçPí2vË«ôÀ­ýÂ>"¤Å?ß?á^,#¬ÙgWáëi/nD³39'ckÖ<5
Ab¸húµ²(xðjî´¨ï£t
ôèÅElrU1ÚÙKÀ­[ixËÚKpÌ-ùÔ·¹uë®3±ÌÑÑÅ&EL±!¼#ª?ýóVã»\rò­Ñ4 ¤ÍThzgò£íIß?W:$Ó
Cö¨ÿ½IöÏñ
9X{Ó6P&CÑçKæ/­@&ÁM()ûÇ­#0§p+Üª¤,ç¢k¸mÎÌzI®Ë]ËÓf9ä~uÀÞNâÅKdvác{±\óÅMob2k(]¢¿Ì®~«ú²à²H?ÿ*à¾§¡ÊÒ65QÒ*z¤¿(¹U>Á©#+­_1½ËaKS|µ<¹Å5Ô|ÊG¸ªSJí]£5IÜ¥ýCMvÚ)aØFN*k1jKÝóÚ©ü6ø®ytdÜ(eÉã8®sLðÎ£`]=ô¦yv¯]Ö,ã{ÂÎ XÆO¹íXÏà$JWgTj_C{»õ¨cp9Ò£Mka®Ä6pÉk°?fÇC\dúdsòu8b:f±Cx´Ö¦öß8|Cªí\ÂËi!FWÆqZµlÂeæ_Îô:¨ut8ø5¯a~¯?ãàdÓ%wCuµ»däUuÔuósn'-ù¤»ÑëÐÜ+½*vÆ+Ð<SkzPXuSÁPy®àà|Æí¹)½æ\géMgìy¬å»Px¸dµ;ÅÒÜãMÎÞÕÜ)^«sÖÅbÛÊ£u¥óv|VkÜî4ß´ä~´\obõÍÈÚ@ëë\·ü@?¯/ÇÚ=Xð£ó"®ÞÞª+Ã~6x¡næE¶}Ê¾r~Ëý*Ö7RiØªpr<ù®.q#d½Í[°Mßkµ-¡`þ!ÓJÄg!Ü=ÏaO(¤
y/Þ>Ò½©à¯0µ¾ìàqõ§IsórsÞ©´ÛWh5nrMKÜ¤ì¬h±ªfåãâªÈÅ e­;{æ¶"~dp¢´ð3IèTÑMõæwÍ>'$õ¤SfÄsëVRbk.éVùëL"\Í<J
Säæ¦FÇzb%/ëB¾:TLÇ>´éVìü;ãïhjØX_:[«U 6Üõ=?úôW­Çz*
mÝÅ<SÚl<;%ÝÇÚnËÏ3äþu_¡-?tj¨.+rÎÉF8¯&Ý*ìÇÓô(PÝÊ·m4¸(ü«FÚØÕ¡¸8âº#I#Q²µV½ªxíFEYìá+e¹
Û¥YàU6·¥NaVª+©ø`:dSe·uå ¦Cpcm{Ó°
XÜSã®jRÊ¹ªóE$|¡Èô¢À)>¢yèi2¹Úß+z^W§4¬1¤sÈÀvâXcM84¬7
qôjiiGIô£qFö§2ZT3_ahCI¸éã¯188Ít^#¹
7Üå¾µÎÏ$yä\5íÍdzXhµBÇXÒt-V>Ð¤ðE.K×2:Û*m¹${óBÉ4G(å~h¡ÍE"wÅ;`5B÷EôaVtûÖ½ÎhÄdñµp£i8§h²m$µNRãvÇ÷`gµªFç `g§z«m/È9¨î¶¶ôUýã~Õ´bç$eh¦ÙNùÁ[×5"ÂÉï¼Û¤c!$ð
Vº%SiÎO~àS©+½
¦¬aêêY÷Årwè$ù[¯qýk¤×.-£9>¤×
â»Â¶ÈFù%}&±jÎÇL%vK«ÃäqêÀV-æöcyÞy¤p»ãêTWO¸(»xêGY}¢ÖC@õ\ÿ>éÛ©¼¬qêñÅ/r$¸ÁJû÷«í, eq"Øñ]öö·Ql äúqÛ½bOá1+Km<Q3´)@@l£¸·³9{­+Ìí±`8t8#ñ©­¼A©i,#¿S<_óÑ>ðúð­³¤:NHÍãë9ü95[QÓÒT(Ö6@7<Í&=ð@¡Æ/q*rFâ[Kè÷Û]$êä}}+V=K,   `s^qqáÛXgtyxü¿Æ ·¼ñ-ÕïHÄc5§Ùéº=Pj
GÞâ£}ABðÕÁ[jzÑ¸ÒdÕúV¾Ó¨È0ºeïàøÔò±r®VúËíUnut~øÀ÷®KRþÞ[YgKºÄjXïÀWj~1Öµ1Â²[ó­©PMLF&t{ãÏEanð[È$ºqQü>æ¼fk¸¸i¦}ÎÇs3¦º/É9¦wÄ&/}ûÖiÒwËrì{ôhÂ4Õã×©:®ïbÎOVè83s¿Ýa]"ø~ »¼³Wt½%'M£*Øþ¢­Ô²!QmvWÈþ5 Ó.ÛÐWo¦))A_þ½gíY¯ÕÑÁ"ä[ô¨¤Ó'^§ô¯Ck%Ç@
Ï¾²ÀÆ(UIt8¨Q¡mÖ¬ïùj}ZÙ£>`w­QßòÖÛØ¥OUXI¥XãRìO
ìt?j7H²ÎÂ=±O`IÉèbÄÜTêøî+²ÀD©ÿH|aU¯<uà9(º)ÂK¡Î$Àt§³R^èz-õõ^j£ó+¨«HÍèZI
N#j´(O5nãU¤EÇE2ÆÎqE>Pæ>Ú¶¶VÚ®F£Ò¸ãÜ<Uûp2*(­F¢7-ÀÕ³£EQMÊr*Ü7xaUaZ2ÆH¦¥Ä6%SZ»ÈÃ­,K.X¯çEãb9Sg¶IGATnÅ´d´sª·±ª±ëF%]ÀwlT¸³mÑåãî*ÕµÌW×â³'ñ-¶ÃXzÁ¼ñüÈâò?ÃÞ¥»¡'Ðë¯,Ä¹x=gÇpðÉäÜ£zÖñ}ÚñR­T»ñEÄèD¶öçÜçRçh¨Ìì]®å¨C`à×'kâémÔ$â@;îÅ-Ïcuù-|¶õ/éSícÜ~Â}®vE´ªrp+*}rÎÙX,V£ýk»Öå·;3}OJ¨÷¹Åe*Ë¡´0ýÉ5©$$k2WÜ~oÎ¬±Vª²uê+LíH­+4g88õ©§:È£èjoLÓ1$©Ô"ÞÇH¨¤dàSf$~kªùùrpÞÕkÎ,¶­U®Jve[Èb¨XIåÞ²3È«÷_/Ì«èsXEÊ]!æ»T5foNGcop /51`Ñ¨ üçsc®;V6:Ü29ô­ÀªQ×q=®;6g_t.²¹ãÔVMô33 ý+^ufP1ö®gÄóFFìÁ#½)+;¹;ógbI$ó¹ÌºLvË·Û'ý+¶¿¸ò¬]³/5à óËtãvk³®s§°ÄTòä$qôÃã¯­k[F»@Î:Ôw6Ê¤6åÏ½EÙ£ÈÝÉ!ûzñYóI"æ#¡®¦}em¨îþïZÇÁÒ¾ëNz¥mG%Ì%æ2ÀAW¬<?­êX)löÑùi?NµêZ^§éÊE¥¤1?iT/Áâ´ælÅÕkcÎtï[«    /î¤îþUÐ[èÄ6,j z
éÄ+ÎÑz@½qSÊK¨ú¶ú=¿ñB÷â´`Ò­ÿ¨OÊ´cØ©ví^«HÍÌå<_iz5ÖT·N
|ScþÒb+¿Ì;sÓ<×Ú?®ÖÛÂú§ÎñÓ_-Íä%óåíB¾§¯óý+·
´gÞ'QmtÚ[ÛX2«©Ö8.ãïËY×vÒE®Æän"ïËbF77;;V·eðÅÖ9¸KÊ@ù1q¹°tË»ÍGÄ¯s#93ÀÀÏÐwâ¶·Tsß£;  ­øÈ^&/g_á*ó­I¢Ì}6c­VÓPEÁcÏëÿ×¬ÇZZCØë·£S ­»jàÂÜHÏJcõÁ±MáÁ`VæÈrkVEÈ±úûÓD³Õ,ÁÜ0#ä. x&1pOÊ}kÒ¯íÁ8ÀäV7ölwÐ£¨#x­¡+µ)Üè~xf+{E½¹@ÓÈ2þ^;W8à¥/c8U\b¶"`ÿJ$îtB
*È`RNqsB
ò3íRµ,Of98Þô¨¹M·vI!ÆÑí\ö§¤B±{ìî¢àóî;Öeä1¸ùHô­#6*SLá'´&á¨SÛé5Hì!ü+êS§õÕs¤âRÚ£µÖVUyÅYHñDB¬(¬l+b§*pM@äÎ
THI9çQÀÓ7X|"îÙnÎÂpú¨ìÁ¸5{$`»9ªqH´®h=Ál1¶j¤÷dI$V¬övòúÖv¡#s×Ö²Òèm
w5nu^xëY·WÌ$Æ
P¸f8$ò*Ý¶zW<ê³¦4-}¤ãy5]®·ÃåNj¤ $×;¨Ím¥'=Æj$1HÊ~µ
&RB39>iæ¡o»øÖm ÊÝx©ã«5:3Qr{ÿ*f~¥4Mrr=Í&0F;àwúÔ×;Z>qõôª^¥qªy¨?J¢e9ÿw&î}¿lX\?6óØ
cß(6û±ÎÆ§Ð§H®BÁÙªá-;QËcJ
sÚÙå©GÏ2k©Ô@ó£ãªóï\ó·Ú3òîÆ1ìMT¢¹«ðö)~Ë1&È³×oÿ¯ùWbA\çå^ \ÿT.QNIüMoDÅ¡RÇ'µ´6H¶Ûd38òdf'é\Nºâ{ rHÀãõ®Zv`ÅrDò}**¾Õµ9Ìc·©æL
Óð"+8ð¸ãÀñi?o¶¹?Êºo[í\Ò; ½Ó£·åG51U}*qÅ)'+ÏSI+¢Ý ±q3Öµ"ØN85bÝNNp+DÚº/.LÎEKÔÕE'åæ§Õ²nAÀã4ô<`õíP+õíORw{Õ\!ÀÔRÊÎzSÏ¼vòÉÜh¸(sû@jéeàåÜL¾Zç¹&¾mðo©ÙÛÞgÊ¹wN2vü¿©¯[ý¦æi;~G¯¼³Ãÿlè+Ø:{ù¦»ðË÷mf-ÞªF·m?Æ7K>õHt¯ þó¨ôÝ?Éñ:zºÊöÒÊòH2¥xÏ¾I© sñOVb9VéÈÏàü@¾rãqî?Â­½_¡VÔè.Ój@#ûV}Ú,zZz'9'Ê´ÿëþ5ØéêZ
þþ¤
Izv¨²|ò{í²ýò;Vv4CÙòÜ`¥G+aÇñEè
5ùvÏ¥;  ²½À2=+5KØ[ý±Z7'ÇqY<GpþuHw3nUæµm«Åsú[-yíZÇ`çµ6lsÇzVNpk,1Æ3HÎÀÒDÈÓÛ£ò§­U¸q³t ¸ôEfÊí»ïåpUÈ>Õ¥]Ë!ÉUûÖMÁø;M^»v#$õª/÷XÕ%c)ÒEó*vhªæfGÿÙ
```

I want convert this string to jpg file. I tried this code

```
$image = basename($orginalImage);
$imageString = getHtml($orginalImage);
file_put_contents('images/'.$image, $imageString);
```

I can't use copy function. Because i want download image from remote. This site use cloudflare. I use this library for request: 
https://github.com/KyranRana/cloudflare-bypass 
Edit: My all code: 
example.php

```
include 'functions.php';
require_once 'libraries/httpProxyClass.php';
require_once 'libraries/cloudflareClass.php';

$imageString = getHtml('https://coinkite.com/static/img/terminal-v2.png');
file_put_contents('asd.png', $imageString);
```

functions.php

```
function getHtml($url) {
    //ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $httpProxy   = new httpProxy();
    $httpProxyUA = 'proxyFactory';

    $requestLink = $url;
    $requestPage = json_decode($httpProxy->performRequest($requestLink));

    // if page is protected by cloudflare
    if($requestPage->status->http_code == 503) {
        // Make this the same user agent you use for other cURL requests in your app
        cloudflare::useUserAgent($httpProxyUA);

        // attempt to get clearance cookie  
        if($clearanceCookie = cloudflare::bypass($requestLink)) {
            // use clearance cookie to bypass page
            $requestPage = $httpProxy->performRequest($requestLink, 'GET', null, array(
                'cookies' => $clearanceCookie
            ));
            // return real page content for site
            $requestPage = json_decode($requestPage);
            return $requestPage->content;
        } else {
            // could not fetch clearance cookie
            echo 'Could not fetch CloudFlare clearance cookie (most likely due to excessive requests)';
        }   
    } else {
        //file_get_html($url);
    }
}
```

httpProxyClass.php 
https://github.com/KyranRana/cloudflare-bypass/blob/master/libraries/cloudflareClass.php

cloudflareClass.php 
https://github.com/KyranRana/cloudflare-bypass/blob/master/libraries/httpProxyClass.php 
And asd.png http://www.erkinakbudak.com/asd.png

Comment: Did you try: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php?

Comment: Why there is a function for this...

Comment: @Smar Sorry, What do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

> ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿáXExifII*1&i2PhotoScape ô ;ÿÛC  !"

this **IS** JPEG file actually, Just save the data from this response to a file, and you are mostly done.

Comment: I copy all string. I create new file "example.jpg". I edit with notepad++.I paste string and save. But image is not showing. Is it correct?

Comment: Wrong. You should just save this data via your PHP script (i.e. using `file_put_contents()`. If you paste this to notepad then I am sure it will be corrupted by notepad (it's not a tool to save binary data) or because you copied data shown by browser which will be tainted tainted by its fomatting engine. Save it directly.

Comment: It still broken image. I edit my first message. Thank you in advance